# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" on production server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I set up https://github.com/blueimp/Bootstrap-Image-Gallery 
On my Spree shop. 
Everything works well on development machine. 
And I getting the error on production server when press on imge preview. 
Link to page where I getting the error: 
http://vk-magazin.com/products/krossovki-adidas-1
[image: Gallery error]

Comment: It's really hard to debug the minified code even with chrome trying to de-minify it. so best I can suggest is that your code and the minifier are not playing nice together. Make sure your code is passing js(h/l)int before minifying.

Comment: I'm not jquery expert. Is there simple way to debug this?

Comment: Can you show us your un-minified javascript?

Comment: There's near 70 *.js files. Should I upload them in github repo to show them you ?

Comment: Naw man, unless you can narrow it down to a minimal test case I can't really help you further.

Comment: In this this kind of view, fit ? I getting error on the line # 11824 this._loadingImage = loadImage(

Comment: All I can say from that is that `loadImage` isn't defined in the scope of that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Twitter Bootstrap theme with bootstrap-sass gem. 
And made mistake in including bootstrap-sass.
You jast need to create file

tb.css.css in /app/assets/stylesheets/store/

which should contain:

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

To find out you set up right TB, check you tb.css file in sourse code. 
If you see lines with comments like

```
/* /../../..ruby-gems bla bla bla */
.clearfix {
```

You set up TB css right 
For Javascript include 
in app/assets/javascripts/store/all.js

```
. . .
    //= require bootstrap
. . .
```

After this js with TB should work right.